# Nginx redirect to external url or static page

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

We are running Nginx as a proxy in front of a multi-tenant app hosted on IIS. When one of the tenants is down for maintenance I would like to redirect the url to a static web page hosted on AWS S3 or a local static page on the Nginx server.

For example the url may be http://**demo**.myapp.com, so would want demo to be redirected but anything else such as http://**test**.myapp.com to function as normal through the proxy pass to the back end web servers.

I have tried using rewrite / return in a new server block setting the server name to demo.myapp.com and this works redirecting to a static page but it redirects all not just demo.

All the traffic goes to port 80 on the Nginx server and the default location / then proxy to the back end web servers.

Looking for any advice on this as I am new to Nginx and cannot find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the answer is here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: can you share your configuration file

Comment: Thanks for the link VBart, I found the issue was that I was not using the correct location block for the demo server block.

Answer (score 0):

**Nginx external URL redirect**

```
location ~* ^/example/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ https://example.net$uri redirect;
}
```